# How to activate both eth0 and wlan0 simultaneously for sending request via terminal

Tags: curl, networking

This is my route table

`Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.1.1.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0`

I am trying to add different gateway for `wlan0` so that I can some of my requests via `wlan0` and specified gateway without affecting `eth0` with this command

`route add -n 10.1.1.0 gw 10.1.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev wlan0`

but then the existing one is not updating it is adding the new one

`Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.1.1.0        10.1.1.1        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.1.1.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0`

So I am not able to use specifically `wlan0` for sending any requests say `curl` because always curl is sending request by `eth0` even after specifying `--interface wlan0`

Comment: sorry, but this is just a matter of how IP routing works, not a suitable question for stackoverflow

Comment: should I post in server fault?

Comment: perhaps, or just google "ip routing explained" and read up...